# How to kill locked Node process in WSL

Tags: windows-10, webpack-dev-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running my web application in WSL is occasionally getting stuck, I am able to close the script. But the process in the background is stuck and has my files locked.

**Detailed info**

The Web application is running with **webpack dev server** listening on changes in the code. When doing git operations, sometimes the files are **locked** and I cannot perform changes.

I can see the process by running

```
$ps aux
```

[image]
The process is taking a lot of memory.
I tried killing the process with

```
$kill -9 604
$pkill -f node
$kill -SIGKILL 604
```

But none of them works

I even try to kill the process from Task Manager but its still there.

(Windows Subsystem for Linux running on Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Hello same problem on win11

```js
sudo kill -9 2769
```

```html
mike      2769  1.5  5.7 13169872 1914268 ?    Z    11:54   7:42 /home/mike/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.4/bin/node /mnt/d/dev/repo/mikecodeur/react-course-app/example/react-fundamentals/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
mike      2907  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    11:54   0:36 [node] <defunct>
```